Steam not using dedicated GPU. 1st time Linux user here
I am using Ubuntu 24.04
System Configuration..
CPU- Intel Core-i5 4590s
Motherboard- Generic O.E.M board
Onboard GPU- Intel HD 4600 (This GPU is Disabled in Bios)
GPU- Zotac Nvidia GTX 960 (4 GB Single Fan)
Ram- G.Skill Ripzawsx DDR3 1600 Mhz Dual Channel 8 GB total (2 Four GB sticks)
PSU- Corsair VS550

Disk Drives -
1- Samsung SSD 870EVO 500GB Connected to SATA3 (Ubuntu is installed here)
2- WD Blue 500Gb Connected to Sata 3 (this will be steam library)
3- WD Blue 2TB Connected to Sata 2 (general storage)
4- WD Green 1TB Connected to Sata 2 (general storage)

Board also has a Nvme Slot which is currently Empty.
I finally got the courage to dump windows and start Linux. Installed the OS A Couple of Days Ago and it is mostly easy to use. the problem showed when i tried to run game on Steam. it was L4D 2 and the game started fine but frames plummeted to 1 fps. i went to Steam help section and found out the thing is running a software render instead of Dedicated GPU.
for some reason it is using this...
Video Card:
Driver: Mesa llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7, 256 bits)
Driver Version: 4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 24.0.3 - kisak-mesa PPA
OpenGL Version: 4.5
Desktop Color Depth: 24 bits per pixel
Monitor Refresh Rate: 143 Hz
VendorID: Redacted by me.
DeviceID: Redacted by me.
Revision Not Detected
Number of Monitors: 1
Number of Video Cards Not Detected
Primary Display Resolution: 1920 x 1080
Desktop Resolution: 2720 x 1080
Primary Display Size: 20.75" x 11.65" (23.78" diag), 52.7cm x 29.6cm (60.4cm diag)
Primary Bus: PCI Express 16x
Primary VRAM: 9984 MB
Supported MSAA Modes: 2x 4x 8x 16x

I thought maybe my GPU is not initiated or recognized by the OS itself so i checked that first.
Now, were i a command line warrior,i would have typed some impressive lines in terminal and sorted this out.  but i am a windows Noob. so i went about it in a more practical way of checking if my GPU is being used or not.
I installed and Ran Pcsx2 (ps2) emulator and ran God of War 2. and lo behold, the GPU is running fine and the game ran 60 fps no problem.
This is what Nvidia smi gave me..
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.171.04             Driver Version: 535.171.04   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960         Off | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 37%   46C    P0              27W / 120W |    228MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2118      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                          111MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2358      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         31MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2852      G   /usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal-gnome         6MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3521      G   ...seed-version=20240524-161927.269000       70MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

well here i am guys and hope it was not to long to read. i really hope this is a solvable problem as i do not want to go back to windows.
How can I make Steam use the NVidia GPU?
Update on the Problem- as David mentioned maybe Steam has no support for this version yet. but instead of asking in the steam forum and waiting for answer i thought changing the Distro might be faster (it was). Changed to Pop OS Distro and it worked! now i can learn to use Linux and play games, will reinstall Ubuntu when i am good to use it. thank you to all for taking the time to read this.

Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

the latest version it is 24.04

Visit the steam support site and see if they are updated to support Ubuntu 24.04 yet.

I see, interesting. i did not think it could be the case.  from what i understand, there are many GUI based Linux OS, distros they are called. perhaps switching to another one that is proven to work will be faster. i will try the Steam thing too and will update the post if it works. thank you for taking the time to answer guys.

There is a steam setting to use default GPU, but sometimes this need the other setting, even though you think the default should be the Nvidia.  Another thing to check is the power/performance setting in the Ubuntu Settings.  Launch steam from dash using the "use discrete graphics card" menu item. On xorg, the command
xrandr --listproviders

should show your GPUs.  Hybrid laptops sometimes get the source/offload gpus mixed up, but don't think that should be a problem with your desktop.
